# How to extract numbers from a column in a data frame and add them in a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I have a dataframe named `df` and it has one column (`Today's price`) as string values.

Here is an extract of that column:

```
Today's price
MUR 15,265
MUR 20,000
MUR  9,841
```

I need a new column in my dataframe (df) called "Price" (extracted from "Today's price" column) as follows:

```
Price
15265
20000
 9841
```

Here is what I did and I am getting "NA" for all records and it is not creating the "Price" column.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Price = as.integer(str_extract("Today's price", "[0-9]+")))
```

I am using the `dplyr` and `stringr` libraries.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `sub` + `as.numeric`? Could you share your data as a `dput`? try `as.numeric(stringr::str_remove_all(col_name_here, "\\D"))`?

Comment: I have updated my question as I missed mentioning that my codes are not creating the "Price" column, besides giving "NA" for all records.

Comment: Could you add usable data?

Comment: In your `str_extract` (as well as the problems mentioned in other comments) you should reference the `Today's price` column with backticks, not quotes.

Comment: @NelsonGon Works fine! Please post as an answer and I will vote accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `parse_number`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Price = parse_number(`Today's price`)) %>% 
  select(-`Today's price`)
```

Even shorter with:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Price = parse_number(`Today's price`), .keep = "unused")
```

Output:

```
 Price
  <dbl>
1 15265
2 20000
3  9841
```

Comment: I think `parse_number` needs `library(readr)`

Comment: Thanks. Just forgot to put in!. Please see my edit.